# Adding a new line to a file in Python

Tags: python

So I have a file that is in this format (no, this is not what the file looks exactly like)

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddddd
```

I want to append a new line to the file so that it looks like

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

but whenever I use

```
with open(filename, "a") as updatedFile:
    nextLine="\n%s" % (lineToAdd)
    updatedFile.write(nextLine)
```

I get

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddddddd

eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you using windows? Try \r\n

Comment: No, I am on UNIX so \r doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a file that already had a newline at the end:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n
ccccccccccccccccccc\n
ddddddddddddddddddd\n
```

and you wrote a newline plus the additional line:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n
ccccccccccccccccccc\n
ddddddddddddddddddd\n
\n
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Write your additional line with the newline *at the end*:

```
with open(filename, "a") as updatedFile:
    nextLine="%s\n" % (lineToAdd)
    updatedFile.write(nextLine)
```

so that you end up with:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n
ccccccccccccccccccc\n
ddddddddddddddddddd\n
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\n
```

Comment: Ah I see the logic now. Thanks so much for the help!